# Pandas reindexing task based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with millions of rows with unique indexes and a column('b') that has several repeated values.

I would like to generate a dataframe without the duplicated data but I do not want to lose the index information. I want the new dataframe to have an index that is a concatenation of the indexes (`"old_index1,old_index2"`) where 'b' had duplicated values but remains unchanged for rows where 'b' had unique values. The values of the 'b' column should remain unchanged like in a `keep=first` strategy. Example below.

Input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,"non_duplicated_1"],
                          [2,"duplicated"],
                          [2,"duplicated"],
                          [3,"non_duplicated_2"],
                          [4,"non_duplicated_3"]],
                  index=['one','two','three','four','five'],
                  columns=['a','b'])
```

desired output:

```
             a                 b
one          1  non_duplicated_1
two,three    2        duplicated
four         3  non_duplicated_2
five         4  non_duplicated_3
```

The actual dataframe is quite large so I would like to avoid non-vectorized operations.

I am finding this surprisingly difficult...Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` on the index column (after you use `reset_index`). Then, drop duplicates in column `b`:

```
df.index = df.reset_index().groupby('b')['index'].transform(','.join)

df.drop_duplicates('b',inplace=True)

>>> df
           a                 b
index                         
one        1  non_duplicated_1
two,three  2        duplicated
four       3  non_duplicated_2
five       4  non_duplicated_3
```

Comment: I was trying different combinations of groupby/reset_index but I did not know the transform function. Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
dct = {'index': ','.join, 'a': 'first'}
```

You can `reset_index` before using `groupby`, although it's unclear to me why you want this:

```
df.reset_index().groupby('b', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(dct).set_index('index')
```

```
                          b  a
index
one        non_duplicated_1  1
two,three        duplicated  2
four       non_duplicated_2  3
five       non_duplicated_3  4
```

Comment: Your answer works great too but I had to pick one. 
It is complicated to explain why I want this without introducing the dataset and the analysis. Basically, it's because I am generating a large report and I want to avoid the duplication of the values in different indexes.